# When does sólo have an accent? / ¿Cuándo debe llevar tilde la palabra "solo"?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, adverbios

When does the word *solo* have an accent (*tilde*) on the first *o* (*sólo*)? When does it not?

---

¿Cuándo debe llevar tilde la palabra *solo*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should never put an accent in "solo" if you want to follow RAE latest recommendations.

Following accentuation rules "solo" would never have an accent but the previous rules recommend it in cases ambiguity between the adverb and adjective meanings.

According to the [RAE](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#novOrto5) (which haven't updated the DPD yet) the ambiguity cases are very rare and can be solved using other words (solamente, únicamente...)

Comment: I knew the new recommendations said something about it, but didn't know the exact terms. However, I still think there are cases where such an ambiguity can happen and you can't use the recommended means to avoid it. Imagine a poem, where solo is the only word that fits, or rhymes, but the sentence is ambiguous. I know, it's not a common case, but it can happen.

Comment: At First RAE said these new rules where compulsory. After a lot of protests they went back and it's not compulsory so "sólo" is also OK when it means ("solamente"). For that reason the dictionary still keeps both words. They can't change a rule that people uses for such a long time.

Comment: The RAE rectracted on that and the DEM (Diccionario del español de México) usually follows what the RAE says but in this case they didn't accepted that, and some magazines and publishers in Mexico are specifically attached to it.

Comment: Incorrect.  Solo- alone is an adjective.  Sólo with an accent means only and is used as an adverb.

Answer (score 16):

*Solo* has an accent when it means "only" and can be mistaken with "alone":

Compare these two sentences:

> - Voy a estar solo un día. = *I'm going to stay alone for a day.*
> - Voy a estar sólo un día. = *I'm going to stay just one day.*

When I learnt the rule, I was told "si puede sustituirse por *únicamente*, lleva tilde", but the actual rule is, "si puede sustituirse por *únicamente* y puede confundirse con *sin compañía*, lleva tilde". That said, I usually put the accent whenever it means "only".

You can find the [explanation by RAE in the DPD](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=tilde2#323) (Diccionario panhispánico de dudas).

Comment: Like @MarcosPri says, this used to be the rule, but it's now outdated.

Comment: @Petruza the rule is not outdated (this new rule is just a recommendation but it's not compulsory. At first it was but after a lot of complains about it they made it just a recommendation).

Answer (score 5):

**La RAE recomienda que *solo* nunca lleve tilde**:

- Hacerlo incumple las reglas de acentuación.
- En casos de ambigüedad se solía utilizar tilde diacrítica; sin embargo, no era una diacrítica al uso y por tanto dejó de aceptarse como tal.
- Si existe ambigüedad real, la RAE recomienda evitarla haciendo redactados diferentes.

Lo explica con mucho detalle la RAE en [El adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos, sin tilde](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde) (es largo pero se lee bien):

> La palabra solo, tanto cuando es adverbio y equivale a solamente (*Solo llevaba un par de monedas en el bolsillo*) como cuando es adjetivo (*No me gusta estar solo*), (...) no deben llevar tilde según las reglas generales de acentuación, bien por tratarse de palabras bisílabas llanas terminadas en vocal o en -s, bien, en el caso de aquel, por ser aguda y acabar en consonante distinta de *n* o *s*.
>
> Aun así, las reglas ortográficas anteriores prescribían el uso de tilde diacrítica en el adverbio solo (...) para distinguirlos (...) del adjetivo solo (...), cuando en un mismo enunciado eran posibles ambas interpretaciones y podían producirse casos de ambigüedad, como en los ejemplos siguientes: *Trabaja sólo los domingos* [= ‘trabaja solamente los domingos’], para evitar su confusión con *Trabaja solo los domingos* [= ‘trabaja sin compañía los domingos’] (...).
>
> Sin embargo, ese empleo tradicional de la tilde en el adverbio *solo* (...) no cumple el requisito fundamental que justifica el uso de la tilde diacrítica, que es el de oponer palabras tónicas o acentuadas a palabras átonas o inacentuadas formalmente idénticas, ya que tanto solo como los demostrativos son siempre palabras tónicas en cualquiera de sus funciones. Por eso, a partir de ahora se podrá prescindir de la tilde en estas formas incluso en casos de ambigüedad. **La recomendación general es, pues, la de no tildar nunca** estas palabras.
>
> Las posibles ambigüedades pueden resolverse casi siempre por el propio contexto comunicativo (lingüístico o extralingüístico), en función del cual solo suele ser admisible una de las dos opciones interpretativas. Los casos reales en los que se produce una ambigüedad que el contexto comunicativo no es capaz de despejar son raros y rebuscados, y siempre pueden evitarse por otros medios, como el empleo de sinónimos (*solamente* o *únicamente*, en el caso del adverbio *solo*), una puntuación adecuada, la inclusión de algún elemento que impida el doble sentido o un cambio en el orden de palabras que fuerce una única interpretación.

Comment: Cuando en el español es tan fácil ser preciso la RAE es siempre tan ambigua. En lugar de decir "la regla es..." dicen **"recomendación general"** . En el comentario de la respuesta de 2012 ya @Juanillo hablaba de la confusión.