# Removal of accents from demonstratives

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, pronombres, rae

I learned in high school that one must add an accent mark on the stressed vowel of the demonstrative pronouns, while no accent is required for the identical adjectives.

> Ex. : ése (noun) vs. ese (adjective)

Multiple sources have expressed that the RAE had removed these accent marks from all demonstratives sometime in the late 1990s. What is the reasoning for this? I personally prefer the distinction because of the greater clarification associated with it.

Comment: Related: [When does sólo have an accent? / ¿Cuándo debe llevar tilde la palabra “solo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1123/1674) - [What semantic accents did people need to stop using as a result of the 2010 Revision?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25990/1674) and [El adverbio “solo” y los pronombres demostrativos sin tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17599/1674) (answers in all of them quote the same article by RAE).

Comment: @fedorqui should we mark it as a duplicate even if the other question is all in Spanish? If the question is made in English we are not sure if the OP fully understands the other answer. Just asking.

Comment: @fedorqui perhaps we should have a principle about what happens in these case. I have some sympathy with the view that this is not a duplicate for the reasons DGaleano outlines.

Comment: @DGaleano good point! We talked about it in Meta some time ago: [¿Deberían considerarse como duplicadas preguntas iguales formuladas en diferentes idiomas?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2524/1674) and the consensus was to mark them as so. Ideally also we could mark them as canonical and attach a translation to make them understandable in both languages. What do you think?

Comment: @mdewey I also do think so! I would go for keeping a bilingual canonical. See my comment above.

Comment: Please see related meta question: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3076/9385

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [RAE themselves](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde):

> [...] *ese empleo tradicional de la tilde en el adverbio* solo *y los pronombres demostrativos [para distinguirlos, respectivamente, del adjetivo* solo *y de los determinantes demostrativos] **no cumple el requisito fundamental que justifica el uso de la tilde diacrítica, que es el de oponer palabras tónicas o acentuadas a palabras átonas o inacentuadas formalmente idénticas**, ya que tanto* solo *como los demostrativos son siempre palabras tónicas en cualquiera de sus funciones. Por eso, a partir de ahora se podrá prescindir de la tilde en estas formas incluso en casos de ambigüedad. La recomendación general es, pues, la de no tildar nunca estas palabras.*

**Bold** and [annotations] mine.

Translation:

> That traditional use of the accent mark in the adverb *solo* and demonstrative pronouns [to tell them apart from, respectively, the adjective *solo* and demonstrative determinants] **does not fulfill the fundamental requisite that justifies the use of the diacritic accent, which is to distinguish stressed or accented words from formally identical unstressed or unaccented words**, since both *solo* as well as the demonstratives are always stressed words in any of their usages. Because of this, from now on the accent mark may be dispensed when writing these words, even in case of ambiguity. The general recommendation, thus, is to never put an accent mark in these words.